# LINQ - Group by one column and Count() rows (extension method)

Tags: c#, linq

I have a database that looks like this:

```
ID DocumentName Name
1 Test1.txt Alan
2 Test2.txt Alan
3 Test3.txt Jane
4 Test4.txt Alan
5 Test5.txt Bob
```

Now I want to use a LINQ query that will give me this result, using a key of name and the count of the rows per name:

```
Name Count
Alan 3
Jane 1
Bob 1
```

Please can you answer using extension methods? I feel like I am missing something simple, but I can't seem to find the answer.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Look at what GroupBy allows you to do (hint: you can project the "collection of results with this key" to another value...)

Comment: You even have mentioned `GroupBy` and `Count` in your question's title. So i'm suprised that you still have no clue. What was the challenge/issue?

Comment: Yes, see my comment to Jamiec's answer to see what I tried. Thanks!

Comment: For future reference, include the code you've tried and that is not working.

Comment: Yup, I will do that next time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not much to it really, a [`GroupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534501%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and then a projection to an anonymous type using [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548891%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

```
var result = db.DocumentTable.GroupBy(t => t.Name)
                             .Select(g => new {
                                            Name = g.Key,
                                            Count = g.Count()
                                          }
                                    );
```

Comment: Ah thanks. I was doing this, except I wasn't doing g.Key, rather trying to find g.Name again. Cheers!

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped.

Comment: You could also roll the `Select` into the `GroupBy` if you prefer: `var result = db.DocumentTable.GroupBy(t => t.Name, (k, g) => new { Name = k, Count = g.Count() });` (Although, tbh, separating the calls probably makes it a bit more readable.)